# How can I go to the beginning of main function from a sub function in C programing language?

Tags: c, function

I am writing a C code, this code consist with many sub functions and also within a sub function there is another sub function after execution of this sub sub function I need to go back in the beginning of main function.

My question is how can I exit from this function and come back main function?

As this code is too big That is why I have not include this code in here.I think `return;` cant do this thing because it returns only to the function where it got function call. I am beginner in C programming so please suggest what thing I have to do for this?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps construct a small example to demonstrate what you are trying to do

Comment: You should probably start your main function with a loop if that is the case, but we can't say for sure without knowing more and seeing the relevant code

Comment: 60 years after the development of structured programming principles, you really don't want to do that. If you are working in software development and do that, it may seriously harm your career! Learn to design and write code properly.

Comment: @EdHeal : I am specifically referring to *structured programming* rather then programming in general. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming

Comment: @EdHeal Sir, I have given the flow diagram of this program please check it up.

Comment: @o_weisman  Sir, I have given the flow diagram of this program please check it up.

Comment: Learn to use return and pass back the reason. Then the caller acts appropriately.

Comment: @Clifford  You are right I am not strong in C basically this code for Industrial Embedded project. This project has been Implemented on PLC and Running successfully now we want to drag this algorithm into Microcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THIS ANSWER NEEDS A HEALTH HAZARD - THIS IS THE WRONG WAY TO PROGRAM**

You can use [setjmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setjmp) and [longjmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/longjmp) to do this.

But **PLEASE** do everything in your power to avoid this - by thinking about the design of the code beforehand

Comment: @Prayuktibid : While this is the way to do exactly what you have asked as ed has emphasised, you *really* do not want to do that. I would hope that Ed is even concerned that you have accepted this answer.

Comment: @Clifford - It is a solution. But the poster does need to have a rethink. I wish the poster did not accept the answer and would go back to the drawing books

Comment: **ANY BODY READING THIS ANSWER  - DO THIS WHEN THERE ARE NO OTHER OPTIONS AVAILABLE**

Comment: @Clifford - Is the warning loud enough

Comment: @Prayuktibid too often people don't think at what an embedded system is. setjmp() and longjmp() are perfectly legal and are the best option to do _what they are intended for_. You must know what you are doing, And I repeat: you must know. But if you know, don't listen to others.

Answer (score 2):

C maintains a stack of nested functions.  If your main program calls function one and that calls function two, you can only get back to the main program by unwinding the stack using a return statement in each function (therefore from two back to one, and then back to main).  So I don't think you can do what you're wanting.  You can terminate the program completely with the exit statement.

Answer (score 1):

Jumping across function boundaries is contrary to structured programming, and while possible (using setjmp(), longjmp()) is inappropriate and unnecessary in this case.

You need not treat function calls as simple sub-routines - they take arguments and return values; the return value in particular is useful in this case for providing information to the caller for controlling program flow.

Based on your (somewhat confusing) diagram:

```
typedef enum tStatus
{
    STATUS_FAIL ;
    STATUS_SUCCESS ;
} tStatus;

void function1( void ) ;
tStatus function2( void ) ;
tStatus function1n( void ) ;

int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        // statement1
        // statement2

        function1() ;
        if( function2() == STATUS_SUCCESS )
        {
            // statement3
        }
    }

   return 0 ;
}

void function1( void )
{
    // do something
}

tStatus function2( void )
{
    // statement1
    // statement2

    tStatus status = function1n() ;
    if( status == STATUS_SUCCESS )
    {
        // statement n
    }

    return status ;        
}

tStatus function1n( void )
{
    tStatus status = STATUS_FAIL ;

    // statement1

    if( !condition)
    {
        status = STATUS_SUCCESS ;
        // statement n
    }

    return status ;
}
```

If you follow the code flow, you will see that when in `function1n()` `condition` is `true`  then `STATUS_FAIL` is returned to `function2()`, which returns `STATUS_FAIL` to `main()` which then causes control flow to return to the top of the `main()` loop.

Note that most simple bare-metal embedded systems do not return from `main()` so an indefinite loop is the normal implementation when no OS or RTOS is used.

Answer (score 0):

Make the inner function return a value rather than `void`. Use that value in the middle function to determine if you should return to `main`.

```
int main(void) {
    f2();
    return 0;
}

void f2(void) {
    if (f1()) return;
    /* ... */
}

int f1(void) {
    if (condition true) return 1;
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```